# Limits a left join?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have a query that pulls the results from a search but I want the left joined results to be limited to 1

Here is the left join:

```
LEFT JOIN #__ezrealty_siteplan AS sp ON sp.listing_id = a.id "
```

What I have tried

```
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM jos_ezrealty LEFT JOIN jos_ezrealty_siteplan AS sp ON (sp.listing_id =jos_ezrealty.id ) LIMIT 1) AS sp ON (sp.listing_id=jos_ezrealty.id)
```

The entire query:

```
   $query="SELECT a.*, cc.name AS category, ee.ezcity AS proploc, dd.name AS statename, bb.name AS countryname, 
u.logo_image AS logo_image, u.mid AS mid, u.dealer_name AS dealer_name, u.dealer_company AS dealer_company, 
u.dealer_phone AS dealer_phone, u.dealer_mobile AS dealer_mobile, u.published AS dealerpublished, sp.tenant AS tenant, sp.spacenum AS spacenum, sp.sf AS sf, sp.image AS tenantimage,
u.dealer_type AS dealer_type FROM #__ezrealty as a"
    . "\n LEFT JOIN #__ezrealty_catg AS cc ON cc.id = a.cid"
    . "\n LEFT JOIN #__ezrealty_locality AS ee ON ee.id = a.locid"
    . "\n LEFT JOIN #__ezrealty_state AS dd ON dd.id = a.stid"
    . "\n LEFT JOIN #__ezrealty_country AS bb ON bb.id = a.cnid"
    . "\n LEFT JOIN #__ezrealty_profile AS u ON u.mid = a.owner"
    . "\n LEFT JOIN #__ezrealty_siteplan AS sp ON sp.listing_id = a.id "
    . "\n WHERE $extrastring AND a.published = '1' $vacant AND cc.access <= $my->gid $wheres "
    . $order.' LIMIT '.$pageNav->limitstart.', '.$pageNav->limit;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * 
            FROM #__ezrealty_siteplan
            GROUP BY listing_id )
       AS sp 
       ON sp.listing_id = a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you could use CROSS APPLY.  In other DBMS, you can use partitioning (windowing function ROW_NUMBER).

For MySQL, one solution is to use a subquery to get LIMIT 1, then join that to the table, e.g.

```
select a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, b.col1, b.col2
from
(
select a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, (select b.id as b_id from tbl_b b where b.a_id=a.id limit 1)
from tbl_a a
) a
left join tbl_b b on b.id=a.b_id
```

Comment: What should I see in it? Please try applying what I have given you. You can take all the left joins into subqueries at the SELECT level, then LEFT join again against the LIMIT-ed 1 values.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks this will give you what you want

```
SELECT DISTINCT sp.id ,* FROM jos_ezrealty LEFT JOIN jos_ezrealty_siteplan AS sp ON sp.listing_id =jos_ezrealty.id
```

Comment: Does this accomplish anything similar to this:LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM #__ezrealty_siteplan GROUP BY listing_id)AS sp ON sp.listing_id = a.id 

I have gotten the result I want from using that but how is yours different/better?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure there is any difference or even if my solution gives you the desired results if it does give you the desired results then I would look at the time it takes for the data to be returned